# Retrofit get a parameter from a redirect URL

Tags: java, android, networking, retrofit

I am using Retrofit.

I have an endpoint that redirects to another endpoint.  The latter (the endpoint that I end up at) has a parameter in its URL that I need.  What is the best way to get the value of this parameter?

I cannot even figure out how to get the URL that I am redirected to, using Retrofit.

Comment: having the same issue, any more updates?

Comment: @WenChao I would use an OkHttp network interceptor to grab the resulting Response and get its url.

Comment: Updated with an answer for what this question seems to be asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OkHttp's Response will give you the wire-level request (https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#request--). This will be the Request that initiated the Response from the redirect. The Request will give you its HttpUrl, and HttpUrl can give you its parameters' keys and values, paths, etc.

With Retrofit 2, simply use retrofit2.Response.raw() to get the okhttp3.Response and follow the above.

Answer (score 1):

I am using retrofit. And I can get the redirect url following this way :

```
private boolean handleRedirectUrl(RetrofitError cause) {
    if (cause != null && cause.getResponse() != null) {
        List<Header> headers = cause.getResponse().getHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
             //KEY_HEADER_REDIRECT_LOCATION = "Location"
            if (KEY_HEADER_REDIRECT_LOCATION.equals(header.getName())) {
                String redirectUrl = header.getValue();

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this would be to use an interceptor e.g.

```
private Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        locationHistory.add(response.header("Location"));
        return response;
    }
};
```

Add the interceptor to your HttpClient and add that to Retrofit(using 2.0 for this example)

```
public void request(String url) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.followRedirects(true);
    client.addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor);
    OkHttpClient httpClient = client.build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();
}
```

Now you have full access the the entire redirect history.

Comment: And what is the code for the full access of the entire redirect history ?

Comment: Probably more complet answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667230/how-to-get-the-response-url-from-retrofit

Comment: locationHistory was a List<String> in my case, but could of easily been List< okhttp3.Response>.

That other answer is related to Android, mine is generic Java

Comment: What is the "locationHistory" part referring to?