# How to get the response URL from Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit for REST web services my android project. It works fine overall untill the point I'm trying to read several parameters from the return URL.
For exapmle on the web browser:

1. type "http://foobar.com/"
2. Hit enter
3. it becomes "http://foobar2.com/abc=123"

Now the question is how do I get that "abc=123" value from retrofit response.
Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 24):

I have solve the problem.Here is my solution:

Define a request

```
@GET 
Call<String> getSend(@Url String url);
```

and send

```
Api.get(WXApi.class).getSend(ip).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

        Log.d(TAG,"response.raw().request().url();"+response.raw().request().url());}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Comment: response.raw().request().url(); is not giving me the query parameters "abc=123" of op's question. It's just giving me the full URL

Answer (score 6):

Below is my way: (using `retrofit2`)

- **First: Create an instance of `Interceptor`:**

  ```
  public class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  private String requestUrl;

  public String getRequestUrl() {
      return requestUrl;
  }

  public void setRequestUrl(String requestUrl) {
      this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
  }

  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Request request = chain.request();
      Response response = chain.proceed(request);
      setRequestUrl(response.request().url().toString());
      return response;

  }
  }
  ```
- **Add `Interceptor` to `retrofit`**

  ```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
          .build();
  retrofit.client().interceptors().add(new LoggingInterceptor());
  ```
- **Get `url` from `onResponse()` method**

  ```
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Response<T> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
      List<Interceptor> data = retrofit.client().interceptors();
      if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
          for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
              if (data.get(i) instanceof LoggingInterceptor) {
                  LoggingInterceptor intercept = (LoggingInterceptor) data.get(i);
                  String url = intercept.getRequestUrl();
                  // todo : do what's ever you want with url
                  break;
              } else {
                  continue;
              }
          }
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: response.raw().request().url().toString()

Answer (score 1):

First create a call then print. See example below:

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.getLoginData(phone_number.getText().toString());
Log.e(" Login url", call.request().url().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get this data from Retrofit Callback.
In your Retrofit Service declare method with Callback.

```
public interface YourService {
  @GET("/url")
  JsonElement get(Callback<JsonElement> cb);
}

RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://foobar.com").build();
YourService service = adapter.create(YourService.class)
```

And then handle response url in Callback

```
service.createUser(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
    @Override
    public void success(JsonElement jsonElement, retrofit.client.Response response) {
        String url = response.getUrl();
        // handle url
    }
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    }
});
```

Try to use OkHttpClient. Add dependency in build.gradle and modify RestAdapter

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
   ...

   .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient().setFollowSslRedirects(false /* or try true*/)))
```

Comment: Hi, getUrl() returns the original url, not the one that is redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

I *didn't test it*, but such redirects are sent via the HTTP-Header "Location:".

You might be able to retrieve the Url with the following code:

```
Callback<Void> cb = new Callback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Void aVoid, Response response) {
        String url = null;
        List<Header> headers = response.getHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
            if (header.getName() == "Location") {
                url = header.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        // Do something with url
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }
}
```

One requirement is, that the HTTP client doesn't follow the redirect automatically, but I'm not that familiar with retrofit.

Comment: Hi, I had traced the network activity on the browser, the first response was a 302 and retrofit wasn't able to catch it for some reason, perhaps I will just wait for the future updates. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

when using okhttp
[okhttp-logging-interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor)
In Logcat use tag OkHttp

Answer (score -1):

`Response.raw().request().url().query();`

worked for me.