# Kotlin MainThread

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin.
I have a problem, with "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread".

I have 2 different activity. The principal I use for login, the second for send a get http and receive a json object.

Where is my problem? I wrong to use 2 different activity o the problem is asyncdo? I am in deep sea.

```
class GitActivity: AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.git_activity)

    Recycle_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    Recycle_view.adapter = MainAdapter()


    var url = intent.getStringExtra("URL")

    doAsync {

        fetchJson(url)
        uiThread { longToast("Request performed") }
    }

}

fun fetchJson(url: String) : List<NameFileList> {

    var request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {


        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            print("sono qui")
            print(url)
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            print(body)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            print("Error Failure")
        }


    })
```

}

and my Main Class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    SearchButton.setOnClickListener {

            verifyNetwork()

    }
}

private fun getUsername(): String {

    val username = Username_editText.text.toString()
    Log.d("MainActivity", "UserName is + $username")
    return username

}

private fun getRepositoryName(): String {

    val nameRepository = RepositoryName_editText.text.toString()
    Log.d("MainActivity", "UserName is + $nameRepository")
    return nameRepository

}

private fun verifyNetwork()
{
    if(isConnected(this)){

        val url = CreateUrl().createUrl(getUsername(), getRepositoryName())
        print(url)
        var intent = Intent(this, GitActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("URL", url)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    else {

        //POPUP DI ERRORE NETWORK
    }


}

private fun isConnected(context: Context): Boolean {
    val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val activeNetwork = cm.activeNetworkInfo
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Are your icons / resources appropriately sized for a mobile application? If your assets are too large, inflation could take over the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to use Retrofit + Rxjava for handling Network call.

Retrofit :
https://square.github.io/retrofit/

RxJava :
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

You can also refer this link for check example: [How to get the response URL from Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667230/how-to-get-the-response-url-from-retrofit)